# Simply Javascript to total up form fields, where's my issue?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The goal is to take the number of orders for each type and calculate the total price for all of them when you click total cost. But I cant seem to get it to work google debugger says

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; 13
Uncaught ReferenceError: compute is not defined
```

Edit: Fixed the Parenthesis but now i'm having issues with the output lin that returns the total.

Edit2: added .value to return

**[SOLVED]**

```
<head>

    <title>Coffee Order Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function compute()
        {
            //input
            var french = Number(document.getElementById("french").value;

            if(isNaN(french))
                {
                french=0;
                }

            var hazelnut = Number(document.getElementById("hazelnut").value);

            if(isNaN(hazelnut))
                {
                hazelnut=0;
                }

            var columbian = Number(document.getElementById("columbian").value);

            if(isNaN(columbian))
                {
                columbian=0;
                }

            //calculate 
            var total = 3.49 * french + 3.95 * hazelnut + 4.59 * columbian;

            //output
            return document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="http://uta.edu">
        <table border="2">
        <caption><b>Coffee Order Form</b></caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>French Vanilla</th>
            <th>$3.49</th>
            <td><input type="text" id="french"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Hazelnut Cream</th>
            <th>$3.95</th>
            <td><input type="text" id="hazelnut"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Columbian</th>
            <th>$4.59</th>
            <td><input type="text" id="columbian"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="button" value="Total Cost" onclick="compute()">
    <input type="text" id="total">

    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Order">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear Order Form">

    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: is it typo or not? you forgot to close `number(document.getElementById("french").value)`

Comment: Make sure the user cannot input other than numbers, Number("0x20") will result in 32.
if I were you I would do it like this 
var french = parseInt(document.getElementById("french").value || 0, 10); //10 is for the base (decimal)
That way you don't need to check for NaN when value is undefined and "0x20" will result in 0.

Comment: will have to check it out, I was using parseInt originally but swapped  to Number along the way of trying to figure out what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the ending parentheses for all 3 calls to Number():

```
var french = Number(document.getElementById("french").value;
```

Should be:

```
var french = Number(document.getElementById("french").value);
```

Because of the syntax error, the function is not available to your code within the Body.  Thus, the uncaught reference error.

Comment: Okay so I fixed this thank you can't believe I overlooked this, but now its having problems with the calculation being returned to the total field

document.getElementById("total") = "$" + total.toFixed(2);

i'm getting: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

I took it out of the return and still have the issue

Comment: You can try document.getElementById("total").value = xxx;  (you're missing the ".value" part)

Comment: that would be the problemo!

Sometimes you just need a second set of eyes or you'll never see whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In multiple places parentheses are not balanced e.g.:

```
var french = Number(document.getElementById("french").value --->)<---- missing;
```

The best minimum practice is to put javascript code in .js files, use a tool like [pychecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/) to check syntax of files and then you insert with

```
<script src=".."></script>
```

For even better results use jasmine or a similar framework to test your javascript code first.

Answer (score 0):

All your Number functions lack the closing parenthesis:

```
var french = Number(document.getElementById("french").value);
var hazelnut = Number(document.getElementById("hazelnut").value);
var columbian = Number(document.getElementById("columbian").value);
```